# Vite vanillaJS TailwindCSS url build not working

Tags: tailwind-css, vite

Im building a simple vanilla project with vite and tailwindcss. When doing the npm run dev everything works just fine, but when I do npm run build the builder does not process the main.css file that it is supose to be into the main.js, so all the urls paths in the packed css are unchanged, also the images files on those paths are not being processed either.

My tailwind.config.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  darkMode: "class",
  content: ["./index.html","./main.js","./src/**/*.{html,js,vue,jsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {
        colors: {
            primaryRed: "#ee3124",
            primaryGreen: "#98a73b",
            primaryOrange: "#f69223",
            primaryFuccia: "#e387e6",
            primaryCyan: "#90e1ff",
            primaryPurple: "#af6ef0"
        },
        fontFamily: {
            noto: ["Noto Sans", "Karla", "Ubuntu", "sans-serif"],
            karla: ["Karla", "sans-serif"],
            ubuntu: ["Ubuntu", "sans-serif"],
        },
    },
},
  plugins: [],
}
```

What is supose to be build (and many other clasess like this) with my main.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

.mask {
    mask-image: url("./images/mask-full.png");
    mask-repeat: no-repeat;
    mask-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

My main.js file

```
import './src/styles/main.css'

//...code
```

The code structure of my project is a vanilla js vite template. All my public files are in the public folder and when the build is done all the files and folders are bieng copied, but those specific files and URLs paths in the main.css for the mask are not being processed by tailwind and vite, mask are not bieng loaded in production version therefore the site is broken.

Comment: Do you mind providing you `vite.config.js` file as well (be sure to obfuscate and sensitive data)?

Comment: Also missing `PostCSS`, I believe that's your core issue. See suggested answer posted below.

Answer (score 0):

After a couple minutes of researching your issue, it's pretty evident that steps were missed during the setup of a VanillaJS + Vite + TailwindCSS site.

In order to fix the issue, review and closely follow the steps outlined in the documentation (https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/using-postcss) paying *particularly close attention to point #2* related to `Add Tailwind to your PostCSS configuration`.

I believe a step was missed during setup (as there is no mention of PostCSS or its configuration above).